# Error for bind data values in html.index with AngularJS

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

i am using AngularJS and I am not able to populate the data in index.view with the ng-repeat of angular.

I'll leave the code snippet for any help.

Remember, I have the status of the http 200 requests ok, just when I connect the data on the screen, I can not fill.

registerController.js

```
angular.module('Application').controller('registerController', 
function($scope,            
$http, registerService) {
$scope.registerUser = {};    
$scope.GetAllRegisters = function () {

    var registerServiceCall = registerService.GetRegisters();

    registerServiceCall.then(function (results) {
        $scope.registers = results.data;

    }, function (error) {
        $log.error('ERRO');
    });
};


$scope.GetAllRegisters();

});
```

My service.js

```
angular.module('Application').factory('registerService', function ($http) {
return {
    GetRegisters: function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: "http://localhost:51734/api/UserAPI"
        })
    },
};

});
```

And my index.html

```
 <div class="row" style="">
    <table class="table table-striped" style="">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <th style="display:none">Id</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Sobrenome</th>
                <th>Ativo</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
                <th>Remover</th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="registerUser in registers" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                <td style="display:none">{{registerUser.UserId}}</td>
                <td>{{registerUser.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{registerUser.LastName}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="registerUser.IsActive" disabled /></td>
                <td>{{registerUser.Email}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" ng-click="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                <td>
                    <a href="" ng-click="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
                </td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is $scope.registers once the page loads?

As it stands right now your table will not render correctly because you cannot use ng-repeat on a tr because it will be inserted as a block-level element which will blow up your table. However, the data should still be inserted above your table. You will have to call ng-repeat on a custom directive to render the table properly.
Something like this:

```
 <register-user-row ng-repeat="registerUser in registers"><register-user-row>
```

Then in the directive:

```
angular.module('Application').directive('regusterUserRow', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "directive path here",
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true
  }
})
```

And the directive's html:

```
<tr style="word-wrap: break-word;">
  <td style="display:none">{{registerUser.UserId}}</td>
  <td>{{registerUser.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{registerUser.LastName}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="registerUser.IsActive" disabled /></td>
  <td>{{registerUser.Email}}</td>
  <td>
    <a href="" ng-click="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="" ng-click="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Note: You were also missing a closing  after your first link in the .

Comment: I created the directive but I continue with the bug, I have debugged the javascript controller.js file it looks for the method in my service and returns the api result, but when it connects to the table the data that already exists in the database, in a list in my view, I'm not getting any

Comment: Did you already figure this out? There are a lot of issues that could be causing this.If you log the actual response within your service method does the response contain the proper data? If so then the disconnect is between the angular service and controller, if not the disconnect is with you backend.